# void double pointer to other types

Tags: c, pointers

```
typedef struct
{
    void **heapArr;
    int last;
    int capacity;
    int (*compare) (void *arg1, void *arg2);
} HEAP;

int heap_Insert( HEAP *heap, void *dataPtr);
```

I was doing my assignment of insert data to heap with abstract data type.
I allocated memory to heap, but I got problem of inserting data to heap.
I can't find out how to make void double pointer to char or int arrays.

```
void *x=dataPtr;
heap->(*heapArr)=&x;
```

I tried this way but I got failed. How can I make void double pointer to other type?

Comment: *but I got failed* is not a useful description. If you get an error from your compiler, show the exact and complete error message. If you see a runtime error, tell us what you see.

Comment: `heap->(*heapArr)` The arrow operator is used to address members of a struct. `*heapaddr` is not a member. `heapaddr` is. If you want to dereference that pointer you need to move the `*` to the front: `*(heap->heapaddr) = &x;` or `heap->heapArr[0] = &x;` As you don't show how you've allocate memory, I can't tell if that usage is correct.

Comment: @Gerhardh 
Thank you for your answer
I also need to print the member of heap. but I think  `heap->heapArr[0] = &x; ` save address of data. what should I do to save data in array?

Answer (score 1):

Why heapArr is a double pointer ? I think a single pointer is enought...

```
typedef struct
{
    void *heapArr;
    int last;
    int capacity;
    int (*compare) (void *arg1, void *arg2);
} HEAP;

int heap_Insert( HEAP *heap, void *dataPtr){
    heap->heapArr = dataPtr;
    return 0;
}


int main(void){
    char str[] = "hello";
    HEAP heapString;
    heap_Insert(&heapString, str);

    char * str_get = heapString.heapArr;
    printf("%s\r\n", str_get );


    int val = 101;
    HEAP heapInt;
    heap_Insert(&heapInt, &val);

    int * int_get = heapInt.heapArr;
    printf("%i\r\n", *int_get);
}
```

Comment: I need to put strings also. so I think it uses double pointer

Comment: @jnuo that doesn't matter. If you want to store a `char**` into a `void*` you're completely free to do so. Just make sure when you're planning on using it later that you remember it was, in fact, a `char **` and act accordingly. `void**` is a specific pointer-to-type (specifically, a pointer to pointer-to-void). You rarely have to use multi-indirection with `void` because you're nearly always implicitly converting the address *back* to something that is already multi-indirected.

Comment: @jnuo : I updated my code with string and integer example ;)

Comment: ... heapArr is a pointer to which you can point any kind of variable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert void* to char*, then following is the method -
(say void *data)

```
char *a = (char*) data;
```

Similarly for double pointer,

```
char **a = (char**) heapArr;
```

Simply typecast will do the conversion. Please try and comment back what you see.

Comment: `HEAP *heap;
    char**a=heap->((char**)heapArr);` I tried this way but I got error: expected identifier before ‘(’ token

Comment: Casting to/from `void*` to other pointer types is not necessary in C. It is implicit. `char *a = data;`, where `data` is declared elsewhere as `void *data;` is sufficient. Basic rules of C: 1. Don't cast were you don't have to, and 2. Don't cast even where you think you have to, because you're probably doing something wrong.

Comment: char ** a=(char ** ) heap->heapArr; try this

Comment: yes, according to @WhozCraig, you can avoid typecasting.